# Inner join table Cross join on two tables and Array parameter with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to run the following query using Laravels Eloquent style:

```
             SELECT fau.delivery, fau.updated_at, f.name fname, frm_b.name bname, frm_b.hectares, c.id cid, c.name cname 
                    FROM fertilappuser as fau
                    INNER JOIN users_farms as userf CROSS JOIN farms f 
                        ON (fau.usersfarm_id = userf.id AND userf.farm_id = f.id) 
                    INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c 
                     ON (fau.block_id = frm_b.id AND frm_b.crop_id = c.id) 
                    WHERE userf.farm_id IN (9, 17, 27) AND fau.view_application = 1
                    GROUP BY fau.id 
                    ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

I tried:

```
                   DB::select('SELECT fau.delivery, fau.updated_at, f.name fname, frm_b.name bname, frm_b.hectares, c.id cid, c.name cname  ' .
                    ' FROM fertilappuser as fau ' .
                    ' INNER JOIN users_farms as userf CROSS JOIN farms f ' .
                        ' ON (fau.usersfarm_id = userf.id AND userf.farm_id = f.id) ' .
                    ' INNER JOIN farm_blocks as frm_b CROSS JOIN crops c ' .
                        ' ON (fau.block_id = frm_b.id AND frm_b.crop_id = c.id) ' .
                    'WHERE userf.farm_id IN ? AND fau.view_application = ? ' .
                    ' GROUP BY fau.id ' .
                    ' ORDER BY f.name ASC ', [$farm_ids, 1]
```

Where `$farm_ids` is an array of id numbers i.e. `$farm_ids = $farms->pluck('farms.id')->toArray();`.
I also tried imploding the array with ',' separated values.

But this is not working. It gives a `Syntax error or access violation: 1064  near the WHERE IN clause` So I tried Eloquent:

```
                    FertilAppUser::select('fertilappuser.delivery', 'fertilappuser.updated_at', 'farms.name as fname', 'farm_blocks.name as bname', 'farm_blocks.hectares', 'crops.name as cname')
                        ->leftJoin('users_farms', 'fertilappuser.usersfarm_id', '=', 'users_farms.id')
                        ->leftJoin('farms', 'users_farms.farm_id', '=', 'farms.id')
                        ->join('farm_blocks', function($join) { 
                            $join->on('fertilappuser.block_id', '=', 'farm_blocks.id');
                            $join->on('farm_blocks.crop_id', '=', 'crops.id');
                        })
                           ->groupBy('fertilappuser.id')
                        ->orderBy('fertilappuser.id', 'desc')
                        ->where('fertilappuser.view_application', '=', 1)
                        ->whereIn('users_farms.farm_id', $farm_ids)
                        ->get();
```

But this gives a `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'crops.name'` error.  So it does not see the `Crops` table.

Can someone point me in the right direction to return a result with eloquent?

Comment: I don't see `crops` table included in join ? How do you expect it to work you need to include a join for `crops` table

Comment: Does the crops table exist?

Comment: Your correct.  The Eloquent could be simplified with changes `
                    ->leftJoin('farm_blocks', 'fertilappuser.block_id', '=', 'farm_blocks.id')
                    ->leftJoin('crops', 'farm_blocks.crop_id', '=', 'crops.id')`  Then it returns a result.  Seems I did not understand the join.

Comment: Interesting though when using Laravels' DB class and changing the `WHERE` clause to ```'WHERE userf.farm_id IN ( '. $farm_ids .' ) AND fau.view_application = ? '``` .  It actually returns something then.  But sql injection seems likely with this style.